# Riemann double integration code review in python

Tags: python

The code below is returning 9.000 instead of 6.393. Why is that? This is double integration using Riemann sums. The function calculate should be implemented using math library only.

```
dx = 0.001
dy = 0.001

def calculate(func, xa, xb, ya, yb):
  n = int(xb/dy)
  m = int(yb/dx)
  total = 0
  for i in range (1,n+1):
    for j in range (1,m+1):
      total += func(xa, ya)*dx*dy
  return total

def r(x, y):
  return math.cos(x) + math.sin(y)

l = calculate(r, 0, 3, 0, 3)
print("{:.3f}".format(l))
```

Comment: division before converting to an integer look suspicious

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I've not learnt Riemann Sums before so just taking information from other sources,  I'm not convinced you are using ```func(xa, ya)``` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem is, you need to increment the xa and ya in the loop. Also n and m need to be calculated from the x and y intervals. Otherwise, nice one:)

```
dx = 0.001
dy = 0.001

def calculate(func, xa, xb, ya, yb):
    n = int((xb-xa)/dy)
    m = int((yb-ya)/dx)
    total = 0
    for i in range (1,n):
        
        for j in range (1,m):
            total += func(xa+dx*i, ya+dy*j)*dx*dy
    return total

def r(x, y):    
    return math.cos(x) + math.sin(y)

l = calculate(r, 0, 3, 0, 3)
print("{:.3f}".format(l))
```